# HR said they'd get back to me in 2 days but it's been a week. Should I email them?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process

I applied to a software position on March 6th. On March 7th, HR emailed me mentioning that my qualifications might match their job posting, and requested me to do a code review (review code written by someone else. highlighting any issues I find). I did that and got back to them on the same day. HR then said thanks and that they will look over it and get back to me in a day or two.

It's been 6 days now and I'm wondering if I should email them, and what I should say in the email? I was thinking emailing them this:

```
Hi HRsName,

I am very interested in the software developer position at companyName. 
I was wondering if you can give me a status update on how the hiring process is going?

Thanks,
MyName
```

Comment: yes, ask them what is going on - don't overthink it. out of interest, what happened with your startup? http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/as-the-20-year-old-ceo-of-a-startup-it-company-what-can-i-do-to-get-older-more

Comment: No, you shouldn't email them.  You should pick up the phone and call them.  Be polite and ask what the next steps are.